# Create combinations from the list without considering adjacent elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I want to generate combinations from the list without considering the adjacent elements.

I have tried a code which provides combinations without considering adjacent elements, and it works with unique elements in the list.
But it does not work with repeat elements in the list Eg. [4,5,4,3]

Code:

```
import itertools

b = []    
stuff = [4,5,4,3]

for L in range(2, len(stuff)+1):

    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        a =list(subset)       

        for i in range(1,len(a)):  

            if stuff.index(a[i-1]) == stuff.index(a[i])-1:

                a.clear()

                break

            else:

                b.append(a)

print('b = ',b)
```

Expected result = `[[4,4],[4,3],[5,3]]`

Actual result = `[[4, 4], [4, 3], [5, 4], [5, 3], [4, 3], [4, 4, 3], [4, 4, 3], [5, 4, 3], [5, 4, 3]]`

I can explain with example: Suppose list is [1,2,3,4,5], then the possible non adjacent combinations are [[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5],[3,5],[1,3,5]]. I want these combinations. The code which I am trying works well with unique set but when there is repetition of numbers in the given list such as [1,3,2,3,2,5], then while taking index it always take first 3 and not other one. So how to get the combinations from this set

Comment: Please describe in more detail what the code should do.

Comment: A useful step would be to realize that the approach you are taking cannot possibly work.  When your loop variable `subset` is (4, 3), is the "4" the FIRST 4 in `stuff` or the SECOND 4?  You can't tell.  You solve this problem not by generating combinations of the elements of `stuff`, but by generating combinations of indices 0, 1, 2, 3 ...N-1, where N is len(stuff).  You make all the combinations of indices, and then throw out the ones that contain adjacent indices.  Take the combinations that are left and convert the indices to the original elements of `stuff`.

Comment: Your problem is under specified. No one is going to be able to provide meaningful advice until you provide a better description of the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating all the `itertools.combinations` and then filtering out the valid ones with `index`, which (a) is very inefficient and (b) does not work with duplicate elements, you should implement your own `combinations` algorithm, which is not too hard at all, and might look somewhat like this:

```
def comb(lst, num):
    if num == 0:
        yield []
    if 0 < num <= len(lst):
        first, *rest = lst
        for c in comb(rest, num-1):
            yield [first] + c
        for c in comb(rest, num):
            yield c
```

To add the "no adjacent elements" constraint, simply keep track of whether you took the last element, and only add the next element if this is not the case:

```
def comb_no_adj(lst, num, last=False):
    if num == 0:
        yield []
    if 0 < num <= len(lst):
        first, *rest = lst
        if not last:
            for c in comb_no_adj(rest, num-1, True):
                yield [first] + c
        for c in comb_no_adj(rest, num, False):
            yield c
```

Example combinations for `comb_no_adj([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)` are `[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]` (This example does *not* contain duplicates, simply for the sake of being easier to understand; since this algo does not use `index`, duplicate elements are not an issue.)

---

Update: In fact, first generating *all* the combinations and then filtering invalid ones *can not work*. Consider this example: `[1,1,1]`. All combinations with two elements would be `[1,1], [1,1], [1,1]` (the first and second, first and third, and second and third `1`). How would you decide which of those to keep and which to discard? And it gets worse for `[1,1,1,1]`. (You *could* generate all combinations of element-index-pairs and then filter those, though, but due to the large number of combinations that will be filtered out anyway this would still be less efficient.)